# sort a map of structs in golang

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map which is like this

```
Key: 9970DLXEVOQ0O Value: [{9972IOFNIDER6 0.3},{9972MFYWYJIEK 0.2},{9972QIUUINW6R 0.5}]
Key: 9970DLXEVOQ01 Value: [{9972IOFNIDER6 0.3}]
Key: 9970QYPOYUUIO Value: [{9972VOFA3OJLK 0.4}]
```

in golang named **product_deal** in which **key** is string and **value** is a struct :

```
type product_detail struct {
     deal_id string
     rating float64
}
```

I need to sort the values based on ratings(descending ) in each value field the output should be i.e

```
Key: 9970DLXEVOQ0O Value: [{9972QIUUINW6R 0.5},{9972IOFNIDER6 0.3},{9972MFYWYJIEK 0.2}]
Key: 9970DLXEVOQ01 Value: [{9972IOFNIDER6 0.3}]
Key: 9970QYPOYUUIO Value: [{9972VOFA3OJLK 0.4}]
```

Any ideas of how this needs to be done. i did have a look at other post which sort maps but could not get the implementation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maps in Go are inherently unordered data structures. There is no guarantee that the order is the same between two different iterations of the same map. Inserting a new value may change all of that. If you require sorting, you will have to use slices or arrays.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a shortcoming of Go's map implementation. This is just a characteristic of Hash tables in general.

Comment: So do we need to overwrite the sort method of slice ?

Comment: A slice doesn't have a sort method by default. You define something like `type Deals []*product_deal` and make sure it implements all methods of `sort.Interface` (http://godoc.org/sort#Interface). Then you can call `sort.Sort(myslice)` on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand on my comment on the original question, here is a working example which can be run on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Yje_EWkCyU). Note that I may have misinterpreted the structure of the types you want to have, but the idea should be clear.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sort"

type Product struct {
    Id     string
    Rating float64
}

type Deal struct {
    Id       string
    products []Product
}

type Deals []Deal

// Ensure it satisfies sort.Interface
func (d Deals) Len() int           { return len(d) }
func (d Deals) Less(i, j int) bool { return d[i].Id < d[j].Id }
func (d Deals) Swap(i, j int)      { d[i], d[j] = d[j], d[i] }

func main() {
    deals := Deals{
        {"9970DLXEVOQ0O", []Product{{"9972MFYWYJIEK", 0.2}}},
        {"9970DLXEVOQ01", []Product{{"9972IOFNIDER6", 0.3}}},
        {"9970QYPOYUUIO", []Product{{"9972VOFA3OJLK", 0.4}}},
        {"9970DLYKLAO8O", []Product{{"9972IOFNIDER6", 0.3}}},
        {"9970QYPMNAUUI", []Product{{"9972QIUUINW6R", 0.5}}},
    }

    sort.Sort(deals)

    for _, d := range deals {
        fmt.Println(d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to mention that I need to sort based on ratings (descending). Also I have changed my implementation a little bit , I will edit the question and mention it there.

Comment: That is easy enough to do by changing the implementation of `Deals.Less`.

Comment: Will the implementation still remain the same after the logic has changed.

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that the list is then sorted by rating instead of the Id.